# Selenium script throwing exception as org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException even though there is no Alert

Tags: selenium, unhandled-exception

I am running my selenium script which is based on Java and using Firefox gecko driver. The script, on navigating to a page it is throwing an exception and terminating, "UnhandledAlertException". I don't see any Alerts in the page when I navigated manually. Please help on this.

Comment: You should run the test in debug mode and step through the script starting just before the line where it is throwing the exception.  You'll likely find that the app is behaving differently when driven by your test versus when you interact with it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in try/catch, while debugging your script in runtime:

```
try {
  // execute your selenium script here
} catch (UnhandledAlertException unhandledAlertException) {
  // continue script on exception
}
```

Comment: I am getting below exception when I tried to catch the exception, but not sure how to handle that:

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 57.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 11348, moz:profile: C:\Users\xx\AppData\Loc..., moz:webdriverClick: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 6.1, proxy: Proxy(pac: http://xxx..., rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 4f0c4114-78e7-4057-9647-faf478cfc243
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//option[@value='8']}

Comment: Please paste the exception you get , I see just session info

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: :*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//option[@value='8']}
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)

Comment: Take the line which got the exception and paste the afterwards code to the catch clause

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:370)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:362)
 at newProj.BRMS.main(BRMS.java:139)

Comment: One thing I wanted to mention is, the script does the Windows authentication which will load the page, after that I am getting this UnhandledAlertException. Not sure if this gives any hint

Comment: Do you have a video recording of your test ? Develop @AfterMethod to take a screenshot on the of the test, and see what's on screen. You can use ashot for that: https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot

Comment: Did you guys find a solution for this? I am having the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it while creating driver instance. Below code is in c#.
Hopefully this will resolve your problem.

```
FirefoxOptionsoptions = new FirefoxOptions
        {              
            UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept,                                           
        };
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```